# Abstract algebra(group theory) - alternative proof (property of general linear group)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, induction, contest-math, alternative-proof

Let: $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $p$ - prime, $Z_{p} :=\{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$, $GL_{n}(Z_{p})$ - general linear group of order $n$ whose elements of its matrices are in $Z_{p}$. Prove: $|GL_{n}(Z_{p}|=\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(p^{n}-p^{k})$

Thought of proving this proposition by the use of induction with respect to $n$, but failed to derive constructive proof(i.e. not relying on principle of mathematical induction). If anyone would be able to post constructive proof, then I would be very thankful.

Comment: I don't see why you consider the inductive proof to be "non-constructive"! The inductive proof essentially constructs the matrices, row by row. See this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164601/compute-the-orders-of-psl2-z-3z-and-psl2-z-5z/2164632#2164632.

Comment: @Kenny Wong Induction assumes existence of conjecture at the beginning of the proof. I know proof of the above proposition using principle of mathematical induction. I only wonder how to construct proof "from scratch" assuming that conjecture is unknown.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

Let us look at a general element in $\;GL_n(\Bbb Z_p)\;$, and at its columns as vectors in $\;\left(\Bbb Z_p\right)^n\;$ : in how many ways you can choose the first column? Well, you can take **any** element in $\;\left(\Bbb Z_p\right)^n\;$ *but one* (can you see which one?), so in $\;p^n-1\;$ ways.

Now, in how many ways can you choose the second column? Any element in $\;\left(\Bbb Z_p\right)^n\;$ will work **except the scalar multiples of the first one we already chose** , so  $\;p^n-p\;$ possible vectors.

The third one: any element but the scalar multiples of *the first two we already chose*....etc. Now deduce stuff.